# Tuple vs * star types in F#

Tags: f#, tuples

Consider the following code:

```
let pair = System.Tuple.Create (10, "foo")       // val pair : int * string = (10, "foo")
let tuple = System.Tuple.Create <| (10, "foo")   // val tuple : System.Tuple<int * string> = ((10, "foo"))
```

1. Why doesn't the two lines yield values of the same type? Does the type of the argument `(10, "foo")` somehow change between the two lines?
2. What's the exact difference between `int * string` and `System.Tuple<int * string>`?

For 2, at least the latter has `null` as a value (this is how this question came up). Are there other differences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two different overloads of `Tuple.Create`:

```
 Tuple.Create<'T1>(item1: 'T1)
 Tuple.Create<'T1, 'T2>(item1: 'T1, item2: 'T2)
```

In the first case you just calling a method with two arguments. So the second `Tuple.Create` overload is obviously picked. No surprise.

But with piping you first create a tuple instance. And then pass it to `Tuple.Create` method. This is what happens in the second example

```
  let intermediate : Tuple<int, string> = (10, "foo")
  let tuple = Tuple.Create(intermediate)
```

With a single argument the first `Tuple.Create` overload will be picked.

Note: *star type* is a way [tuple type names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/tuples#names-of-tuple-types) are written in F#. So `Tuple<int, string, bool>` will be `(int * string * bool)`. It's the same thing.

Comment: You write that in the first case a method is called with two arguments. But is it not called with one argument of tuple type? Otherwise I would expect `Tuple.Create 10 "foo"`

Answer (score 5):

Your `tuple` is a tuple of one (1) element, namely the tuple `10,"foo"`. It is equivalent of

```
System.Tuple.Create(System.Tuple.Create(10, "foo"))
```

Your `pair` on the other hand is a tuple of the two elements 10 and "foo".

So `pair` has type `System.Tuple<int,string>` (which is the same as `int * string`), but tuple has type `System.Tuple<System.Tuple<int,string>>` (which is `System.Tuple<int * string>`)